# How to read a CSV file from HDFS via Hadoopy?

Tags: python, hdfs, hadoopy

I am trying to connect python to HDFS so that I can read that file row by row. I tried reading hadoopy tutorial but it reads data from HDFS which exist as key value pairs. What should be my approach?

I have tried this. http://hadoopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-data-from-hdfs